# Firebase Have to upload image twice to get it to display

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am building a chat app i have a list view setup that loads messages and i have a image picker setup to upload images to firebase and display them in the list view. When i go to upload an image i select the image from a image picker, it gets sucesfuly uploaded to firestore but not displayed and no message object created for it this is the error

```
2019-02-06 16:32:19.032 3810-5272/com.example.android.debateapp E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
    at com.google.firebase.storage.obfuscated.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2:455)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.obfuscated.zzj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2:3435)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.obfuscated.zzc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2:65)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.obfuscated.zzc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2:57)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzc.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

but if i go an upload the same image right after the image will sucesfuly upload and display

I have it setup so that the image will be uploaded to [firebase storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wDgU.png) and then be displayed in the realtime database under the messages object as the image url [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EojwG.png)

code:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        });
        photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                String downloadUrl = uri.toString();Log.d("tag", downloadUrl);
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, downloadUrl);
                mMessagedatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
            }
        });
```

[full code](https://gist.github.com/wazyDex/be1d078f2407e03801cccc8707912501)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `getDownloadUrl()` before the file is finished uploading.

`putFile()` is asynchronous, meaning it returns immediately, and your callback is invoked some time later, whenever the upload is done.  Your code is assuming that the upload either completes immediately, or blocks the current thread until the upload is done.  This isn't going to work.

What you should do instead is call getDownloadUrl() inside the callback, when you know the upload is complete.

```
    photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                    Log.d("tag", downloadUrl);
                    FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, downloadUrl);
            mMessagedatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```