# How to get downloadUri of image from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating an app for my school project, my coding is not that advanced so I apologise in advance for my bad coding. So I'm trying to get the download Uri, so once the user completes the form with the picture, I can upload the details to realtime database to be used in my other parts of my app.

```
//I use this code below, I got it from the Firebase documents//

     ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    // picUri is a globally declared string and I use it to set my database values,
                    picUri=(uri.toString());
                    

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                }
            });
```

I believe it has to do with the fact that Firebase method is asynchronous? So the uri.toString() doesnt get parsed into the global string variable? Because I've been playing around and I realised that when I do the .setValue(object) to write my object to realtime database, the uri does get captured, but that would be too messy and then I wouldnt be able to capture the other values. Ive read around that I need to write a callback, theres alot of guides out there that I've really confused myself here.

Could someone people direct me to a guide or a youtube tutorial on how to understand callbacks and implement a callback to get this value , or issit something else that I'm doing wrong, please advice , thank you.

The photos and the other parameters are being recorded succesfully, its only the picture's uri that I'm unable to capture. (I've temporarily replaced the categoryinput with picUri to run tests easier)

I'm a new user so i cant upload pics but the pic for database and layout is:
https://i.ibb.co/YbdSzwB/databasestack.png

https://i.ibb.co/SVG2zxL/stackoverflow.png

I'll input my entire code just for info

```
package com.example.giventake;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ListPage extends AppCompatActivity {


    /*Declare all variables I'll be using*/
    private EditText title, category, description;
    private ImageView image, image2, image3;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    private DatabaseReference referenceItems;
    private Uri filePath;
    private Uri filePath2;
    private Uri filePath3;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE2_REQUEST = 2;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE3_REQUEST = 3;
    String picUri;
    /*Declare all variables I'll be using*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        /*Initialise all instances of variables*/
        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextItemTitle);
        category = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextItemCategory);
        description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextItemDescription);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewPic);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewPic2);
        image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewPic3);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_list_24);
        image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_list_24);
        image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_list_24);
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        referenceItems = rootNode.getReference("Items");

        /*Initialise all instances of variables*/


    }

    /*This is to upload images from your phones direction*/
    public void onFirstPicClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setType("image/*");
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    /*This is to upload images from your phones direction*/

    public void onSubmitClicked(View view) {
        //Fetching data
        String titleInput = title.getText().toString().trim();
        //String categoryInput = category.getText().toString().trim();
        String descriptionInput = description.getText().toString().trim();
        String itemId = referenceItems.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).push().getKey();
        referenceItems = referenceItems.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(itemId);


        if (filePath != null) {
            StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("Images").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(itemId).child("Pic1");
            ref.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Toast.makeText(ListPage.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ListPage.this, "Picture upload failed" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot
                                    .getTotalByteCount());
                        }
                    });

            ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                    picUri=(uri.toString());

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                }
            });
        }

        //ItemsHelperClass item = new ItemsHelperClass(titleInput, categoryInput, descriptionInput, itemId);
        ItemsHelperClass item = new ItemsHelperClass(titleInput,picUri,descriptionInput,itemId);

        referenceItems.setValue(item).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                        Intent i = new Intent(ListPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                                        startActivity(i);
                                                                        finish();
                                                                        // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        //If it fails to add
                                                                        Toast.makeText(ListPage.this, "Something went wrong, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: The `picUri=(uri.toString())` probably runs *before* your code *uses* `picUri` elsewhere. If you run your code in a debugger and set breakpoints on those lines, you can easily verify this. The fix is always the same: any code that needs the downoad URL needs to be inside the `onSuccess` or be called from there. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563258/firebase-have-to-upload-image-twice-to-get-it-to-display/54563426#54563426

Answer (score 1):

The Java Firebase Android SDK makes heavy use of [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) objects (which are similar to JavaScript [`Promise`](https://web.dev/promises/) objects) where you can chain a number of actions together that need to interact with asynchronous APIs.

A [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) object, has many methods to attach listeners, the main ones you'll encounter are:

- `addOnSuccessListener` - When the task completes successfully, run the given code.
- `addOnFailureListener` - When the task fails, run the given code.
- `addOnCompleteListener` - When the task completes (either successfully or has failed), run the given code.
- `onSuccessTask` - When the task completes successfully, start another task.
- `continueWith` - When the task completes (either successfully or has failed), start another task.

Sometimes if you are dealing with multiple tasks at a time, you'll need to make use of methods on the [`Tasks`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) utility class.

For what you are trying to do, here is a list of the steps you need to take once the user clicks the submit button:

1. Get the values of any inputs (title, description, category, image file path, etc)
2. Validate the inputs (make sure each has a value, no invalid characters, etc) and if invalid, show an error.
3. Create the **private** references you need: a `DatabaseReference` and a `StorageReference`
4. Upload the image file
5. If the upload was successful, get a download URL
6. If getting a download URL was successful, save information to the database.
7. If any of the tasks in step 4, 5, or 6 fail, show an error.

As this is a school project, I'm not going to dive in any further. Study the links above, and you should be able to combine that knowledge with these steps to find the solution.

However, I will point out this bug that will get you into hot water:

```java
String itemId = referenceItems.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).push().getKey();
referenceItems = referenceItems.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(itemId);
```

You assign to `referenceItems` here which messes up your code the next time you hit submit and will quickly make your database look like:

```json
{
  "Items": {
    "-MYu4i_5q-GUETw4WV1i": {
      "title": "my first image",
      "uri": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...",
      "description": "some description",
      "category": "some category",
      "-MYu5jNs2MMJJGB2L7jJ": {
        "title": "my second image",
        "uri": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...",
        "description": "some description",
        "category": "some category",
        "-MYu72gLxsi4M6J9aBAr": {
          "title": "my third image",
          "uri": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...",
          "description": "some description",
          "category": "some category",
          "-MYu78gFeoWhV6OSiF9I": ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or, if you had a syntax error rather than a successful upload, you might end up with:

```json
{
  "Items": {
    "-MYu4i_5q-GUETw4WV1i": {
      "-MYu5jNs2MMJJGB2L7jJ": {
        "-MYu72gLxsi4M6J9aBAr": {
          "title": "my first image",
          "uri": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...",
          "description": "some description",
          "category": "some category"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead, save and use the reference returned by `push()`:

```java
DatabaseReference itemDataRef = referenceItems.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).push();
String itemId = itemDataRef.getKey();
/* ... */
StorageReference itemStorageRef = storageReference.child("Images").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(itemId).child("Pic1");
```